# How to check if a process is already running in mpi4py in Windows environment?

Tags: mpi, openmpi, mpi4py

In my program, I have every process, receiving an array from a procedure and forwarding it to the next two. I start at process 0 (root), and send an array to the next two processes (here:1 and 2). From 1, I can send to 3 and 4 and from 3 I can send to 7 and 8 after first receiving from 1. My problem is that before sending, I need to verify that process 7 and 8 for example are alive or not, and also before receiving check if process 1 is alive.

To be more specific, I have cases where processes are receiving data from processes that have never even run. But to be more specific they always show up in order. See image below for this process 11.

[View this image please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el3Sp.jpg)

Comment: The order in which the console output from different MPI processes gets collected and displayed is not defined and could be completely random. That the output of rank 11 comes before the output of rank 5 doesn't mean that rank 11 was the first to print. The only way to get truly sequential output from an MPI program is to have all text output generated by a single rank, e.g. rank 0.